# HTML encoding/decoding issue, when using JS to get from JSON data sample

Tags: javascript, html, json, encoding, decoding

I have a website and want to display text. The text is in German and comes from a JSON data set I have. This is retrieved from a localhost API URL for now. The German words have the special characters replaced with HTML encoded ones. For example, erzählt is saved in the JSON data as  erz&#228hlt. When I make the textContent of my paragraph tag to the JSON German text, the HTML encoding does not work. It does work however if I just copy and paste it manually in. How can I trigger the encoding to work and have it show correctly?

Code:
Gets random German word from JSON API, puts text into paragraph. Encoding issue.
erz&#228hlt is shown instead of erzählt .

JSON example:
 `{ "id": "32", "ename": "Smile.", "gname": "L&#228cheln!" }`

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
 <h4>German:</h4>
 <div>
  <p id="gname">
</div>

<script>
      const api_url = 'http://localhost:3000/fyp/api/grandom.php';
      
      async function getData() {
        const repsonse = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await repsonse.json();
        var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 16534) + 0);
        const { gname, ename } = data[i];
        document.getElementById('gname').textContent = gname;
        document.getElementById('ename').textContent = ename;

      }

      getData();
    </script>
```

Any help or advice appreciated. If anything needs explaining please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately doing what you are asking for would open your site to XSS attacks. The best would be to fix the part that saves to JSON. Could you show this part too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string contains HTML entities like `&#228` then it isn’t text, it is HTML.

`textContent` expects you to pass plain text to it, not HTML source code.

Use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
const value = "erz&#228hlt";
text.textContent = value;
html.innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<div id=text></div>
<div id=html></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML instead of innetText to solve your problem

```js
function getData() {
  const data =  { "id": "32", "ename": "Smile.", "gname": "L&#228cheln!" };
  document.getElementById('gname').innerHTML = data.gname;
  document.getElementById('ename').innerHTML = data.ename;
}

getData();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h4>German:</h4>
 <div>
  <p id="gname"></p>
  <p id="ename"></p>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: Answers are supposed to solve the problem. If you can’t reproduce it, say so in a comment.

Comment: I am using the HTML unicode call ie ü is &#252.

Comment: Example:  {
        "id": "32",
        "ename": "Smile.",
        "gname": "L&#228cheln!"
    },

Comment: @Quentin I wanted to show the code to get more details. Edited. I'm sorry